# What are the possible locations of the notebook and clipboard in Big Oil: Day 2?

Tags: payday-2

In Big Oil: Day 2, some of the [hints to knowing the correct Fusion Engine to steal are located in a notebook and a clipboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129526/4797).

Since they appear in random locations, or randomly do not appear at all, it would be helpful to know their possible locations to make it faster to look for them or know if they didn't appear in the level.

Comment: Screenshots would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=245702671) looks up to date and contains screenshots for nearly all the listed locations.